# How Sorting according to created_at in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs

I am trying to make an order based on the creation date to use the created_in my model but every time I make a query with the FindAll this brings me the messy data. I made a seeder to fill my database and perform the respect tests and since they have all been created the same date always brings me the messy data even though I am placing the order with descending value. I can notice that he orders me based on the date but does not take the time of the field, so he always brings me in a different order. The funny thing is that I printed the query that generates copy and paste in pgadmin 4 and I always get the same result so I intuited that the mess is not postgres but in dry itself.

Query:

```
const result = await this.contratoPignoraticio.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Persona,
        include: [{
            model: PersonaTieneDocumentos,
            include: [{
                model: Documentos,
            }]
        }, {
            model: PersonaTieneRol,
            include: [{
                model: Oficina,
            }, {
                model: Rol,
                where: {
                    nombre: 'cliente',
                },
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        model: TipoPago,
    }, {
        model: Pagos,
    }],
    order: [
        ['created_at', 'DESC'],
    ]
});
```

[the result of a select * from the table;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHiA1.png)

Stack:

1. NestJS - 6.10.12
2. Sequelize Typescript - 0.6.11
3. Postgresql 11
4. pg - 7.12.1

Answer (score 0):

The image which you linked returns the data in descending order with respect to date and time right? If not can you describe a bit more about your issue?

[image]

Comment: Greetings. I put you in context so that you understand me better. I am using the findAll to obtain all the data of my model but I require them in descending order, for this I use the order as you can see in the query that I place. Now to prove that everything is working correctly, create a seeder that records 100 records, since the next step is to paginate the results.

Comment: But the problem is that it always brings me a different order and when I configure it to show me the query that sequelize generates me and I use this in postgresql it brings me the data correctly. The image that I place shows the result of the query that generates sequelize but at the moment that the json returns it always brings me messy, the funny thing is that if I order it for another attribute that does not happen.